# Is there any way to use the Google Maps Static API to generate topographical maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The [Google Maps Static API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro) can do a lot of things, but so far I haven't found a way to use it to generate topographic (that is, contour) maps like [this](http://www.outdoorblueprint.com/read/how-to-read-a-topographic-map/contours.png), with or without the absolute elevation numbers.  The `terrain` maptype just seems to add shading to indicate elevation.

Ideally, I would like to have the Static Maps API serve me black-and-white contour maps, with contour lines at fixed elevation increments.  I believe I could do the styling easily enough, but I don't know if there is any way to get contour data out of the static API.  I know Google also has an elevation API, but as far as I can tell it is meant to serve the elevation data at a fixed point or 1-D path, not over a 2-D map.

If this is impossible, are there any other services that would allow me to do something similar (request static images of topographic/contour maps centered on a particular lat/long via a URL)?

Comment: Down voting the question without explaining how it could be improved is not super helpful...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to achieve an effect *close* to what I was trying to do using the following request URL:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap
?center=sedona
&zoom=14
&size=600x600
&maptype=terrain
&style=feature:all|visibility:off
&style=feature:water|element:geometry|visibility:on
&style=feature:landscape.natural|visibility:on|color:0xffffff
&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

This renders the following image:

[image: Map of Sedona showing elevation contour lines]

The contour lines only render at zoom levels 13, 14, and 15.  Any zoom closer or further causes them to disappear.  There is no way to control the contour lines: color, line weight, elevation steps, labeling, and so on.  This restricts their use to light backgrounds and areas with significant elevation change.

There also appears to be no way to turn off the elevation shading, which looks cool but is not something I wanted in my maps.  In cities, it can give some very strange looking results.  For example, this is San Francisco:

[image: San Francisco showing elevation shading artifacts caused by buildings]

You can see the somewhat unusual appearing artifacts caused by the elevation shading in this case, which have the further downside of obscuring the elevation contour lines.

So, this is by no means a perfect solution, but I think it's the best that can be done with the current API.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, there's no such feature regarding that. I would suggest to file for a Feature Request in our Google [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com).

Issue Tracker is a tool used internally at Google to track bugs and feature requests during product development. It is available outside of Google for use by external public and partner users who need to collaborate with Google teams on specific projects. You can learn more [here](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/).